# how do i handle all subfolders in a single pass using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a raw_data folder containing 4 folders namely:
`orders`, `playlist_track`, `track_facts`, `tracks`

as below each --

```
./raw_data/tracks/tracks_0.csv
./raw_data/tracks/tracks_1.json
./raw_data/tracks/tracks_2.csv
```

etc...

which should be combined into a single file: `./processed_data/tracks.json.gz`

I have written the following code which reads the csv files and  converts it into json and puts it into
jsonfile/playlist_tracksjson/playlist_track_4.json, how do i handle all subfolders in a single pass over the raw data files????

```py
import csv 
import json 
import pandas as pd
import glob

csv_file = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.read_csv(
        "raw_data/playlist_tracks/playlist_track_4.csv",
        header=0,
        index_col=False
    )
)

csv_file.to_json(
    "processedfile/playlist_tracksjson/playlist_track_4.json",
    orient = "records",
    double_precision=0,
    lines=True
)

result = ''
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        result += infile.read()
    with open("merged_file.json.gz", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(result)
```

But with the folder structure is

```
processedfile/ordersjson/mergedtracksfile.json.gz
```

whereas I wanted

```
processedfile/mergedtracksfile.json.gz
```

how can i handle all files in these folders in a single pass?

Comment: you can try an recursive glob method with Pathlib `from pathlib import Path;Path('parent_folder').rglob('*.csv')`

Comment: @Manakin please check the question, i made some edits

Comment: you can edit the path for the location where you saved it, pass it into open` also you some weird syntax (calling pd.DataFrame on otop of pd.read_csv)

Comment: do `with open("../merged_file.json.gz", "w") as outfile`

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.walk`.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html.

This function walks through a directory and all its subdirectories recursively.